# Cycle through images automatically and also swap out on link hover - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a website that has a series of header images that get swapped out when you mouse over link elements.

Recently, I was asked to make the images loop automatically until someone hovers over one of the links, which would then trigger the header to swap out with the image associated with that link.

With a little help, I managed to get the images to swap out automatically in sequence one time, but (still being a beginner at Javascript) I can't seem to figure out how to get the loop to happen infinitely until someone mouses over one of the links.

Here's my Javascript:

```
$(function(){

  var allExperiences = $('[rel=experiences] > li a').map(function(){
    var $this = $(this)
    return $this.attr('data-name');
  });

  var currentExperienceIndex = 0;

  function cycleImages(){
    currentExperienceIndex += 1;
    var name = allExperiences[currentExperienceIndex];

    $('.banner').removeClass().addClass('banner ' + name);
  }
  setInterval(cycleImages,3000);

  $('[rel=experiences] > li a').hover(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var name = $this.attr('data-name');
    var banner = $this.closest('[rel=banner]');
    banner.removeClass().addClass('banner ' + name);
  });

})
```

And my HTML (example):

```
<div class="banner kitten1" rel="banner">
<figure>
    <img class="kitten1" src="http://s21.postimg.org/bmspmlsib/kitten_1.jpg">
    <img class="kitten2" src="http://s30.postimg.org/dd9km289p/kitten_2.jpg">
    <img class="kitten3" src="http://s17.postimg.org/yjxc8tdnf/kitten_3.jpg">
</figure>
<div class="home-banner-icons">
    <ul class="experiences" rel="experiences">
        <li><a href="#" data-name="kitten1"><span class="icon-events"></span>Kitten 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-name="kitten2"><span class="icon-websites"></span>Kitten 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-name="kitten3"><span class="icon-retail"></span>Kitten 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
.banner {
    background:#000;
    width:100%;
    background:#fff;

}

.banner figure {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}


.banner figure img {
    display:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-animation:fade-in .75s ease-in-out forwards;
    -moz-animation:fade-in .75s ease-in-out forwards;
    -ms-animation:fade-in .75s ease-in-out forwards;
    -o-animation:fade-in .75s ease-in-out forwards;
    animation:fade-in .75s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.banner.kitten1 figure img.kitten1,
.banner.kitten2 figure img.kitten2,
.banner.kitten3 figure img.kitten3 {
    display:block;
    opacity:1;
}

/* style for usability */

.experiences li {
    float:left;
    padding:20px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Here's [a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/4QRjR/3/)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `currentExperienceIndex` goes up every time, but never gets reset. I added this to the top of your `cycleImages` function :

```
    if(currentExperienceIndex >= 2){
        currentExperienceIndex = 0;
    } else {
    currentExperienceIndex += 1;
    }
```

See updated:

http://jsfiddle.net/4QRjR/4/